# Run PHP Script Only When Called From Certain Page

Tags: php

I have a script in PHP that's included on pageX.php through `include_once`. Let's call it script A.php.

One could call this script by navigating directly to it from the browser: www.whatever.com/scripts/A.php.

What I want however is for script A.php to only be accessible through inclusion (on pageX.php) as it contains info that I want displayed on pageX.php only.

Besides using `$_SESSION`, are there different approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a constant within your `index.php`, that would not exist had the included script been called directly. In your included script you check if this constant is set and stop execution if it isn't.

Your original script (`index.php`):

```
define('PROPERLY_STARTED', true);
include_once 'a.php';
```

Your `a.php`:

```
if (!defined('PROPERLY_STARTED')) return;
```

---

Because my comment was deleted for some reason: While this works, it's error prone as you need to add that code to every single file. The established way of dealing with this issue is to only expose the `index.php` in your web root and have the files that should remain inaccessible in a directory outside of your web root so they aren't even reachable via HTTP (see e.g. the accepted answer on the question this is marked as duplicate of)

Comment: While that works, indeed, it still relies on a human never forgetting to add the checks everywhere. It's error prone, and adds bloat everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply don't let `A.php` output anything and use a
   function/method based approach
   a PHP script won't do anything if you have just functions defined in it.
2. Limit the access to your `pageX.php` only (via chmod / htaccess)